# How to define a hasMany far relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, relationships

Suppose you have

```
Facility  1------*  Section  1------*  Session  *------1  Event
```

I.e., a facility has many sections; each section can hold many sessions; each session belongs to an event.

How can I define this as a relationship in the `Facility` model to retrieve all **unique** instances of `Event` that a facility is hosting? I have tried this:

```
class Facility extends Eloquent\Model {
    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('Event')
            ->join('session', 'session.event_id', '=', 'event.id')
            ->join('section', 'section.id', '=', 'session.section_id')
            ->join('facility', 'facility.id', '=', 'section.facility_id');
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm very close with that; Laravel adds a constraint implicitly (`"events"."facility_id" in (...)`) and everything gets messed up.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: from laravel 5.1 docs  : Has Many Through
The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient short-cut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example, a Country model might have many Post models through an intermediate User model. In this example, you could easily gather all blog posts for a given country. [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: I already tried that, but in this case there are two relations in the middle. In fact I have implemented `hasManyThrough` for getting the sessions.

Comment: Unfortunately, `hasManyThrough`  is only 2 levels. You would have to define relation for every model and do this `$events= Facility::with('sections.sessions.event')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closer i've got to my initial purpose:

I created an SQL view:

```
CREATE VIEW facility_events AS
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.id) e.id,
    e.name,
    e.created_at,
    e.updated_at,
    f.id AS facility_id
  FROM events e
    JOIN sessions s ON e.id = s.event_id
    JOIN sections_extended fse ON s.section_id = fse.id
    JOIN facilities f ON fse.root_facility_id = f.id;
```

Then I create the corresponding `FactoryEvent` Eloquent model and, finally, in my class `Facility`:

```
public function events() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FacilityEvent');
}
```

I look forward to see Laravel-only solutions for this. In other frameworks, such as Yii, I have been able to do things like that without the need to work on the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid putting any logic in a relationship method on your models. Instead use eloquent to load your relationships, either one after the other or eager load into the `Facility` model. The latter being preferable.

```
class Facility extends Eloquent\Model 
{
    public function sections() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Section');
    }
}
```

Just make sure each of the models has the correct relationship set up so you can chain an eager load. Such as:

```
class Section extends Eloquent\Model 
{
    public function sessions() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Session');
    }
}
```

Then when you come to load the relationships you can use dot notation to eager load them.

```
$facility = Facility::with('sections.sessions.event')->get();
```

`$facility` will now contain a `Facility` model with nested relationships. You can use some of the different array helpers to extract/pluck all of the events.

Comment: Of course that's an option that I already have implemented. But, as stated in my question, I want unique results for the events. The results are being consumed through a REST API and I cannot afford to send thousands of sessions for a single unique event. What I want is the distinct events that relate to a given facility.

Comment: What I pursue is to be able to do `Facility::with('events')`. If Laravel won't allow me to do that, then I will feel constrained by the framework, whether it is a good practice or not.